# PHP7.4 - error when an array is defined as a constant ()

Tags: php, constants

I get this error when I define an array as a constant with php7.4.

```
*170 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant TIMEZONE_LIST - assumed 'TIMEZONE_LIST' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in ...
```

However the PHP documentation indicates that it is possible to define an array as a constant from version 7.

```
define('TIMEZONE_LIST', ['Africa/Abidjan','Africa/Accra','Africa/Addis_Ababa','Africa/Algiers','Africa/Asmara','Africa/Bamako','Africa/Bangui','Africa/Banjul','Africa/Bissau','Africa/Blantyre','Africa/Brazzaville','Africa/Bujumbura','Africa/Cairo','Africa/Casablanca','Africa/Ceuta','Africa/Conakry','Africa/Dakar','Africa/Dar_es_Salaam','Africa/Djibouti','Africa/Douala','Africa/El_Aaiun','Africa/Freetown','Africa/Gaborone','Africa/Harare','Africa/Johannesburg','Africa/Juba','Africa/Kampala','Africa/Khartoum','Africa/Kigali','Africa/Kinshasa','Africa/Lagos','Africa/Libreville','Africa/Lome','Africa/Luanda','Africa/Lubumbashi','Africa/Lusaka','Africa/Malabo','Africa/Maputo','Africa/Maseru','Africa/Mbabane','Africa/Mogadishu','Africa/Monrovia','Africa/Nairobi','Africa/Ndjamena','Africa/Niamey','Africa/Nouakchott','Africa/Ouagadougou','Africa/Porto-Novo','Africa/Sao_Tome','Africa/Tripoli','Africa/Tunis','Africa/Windhoek','America/Adak','America/Anchorage','America/Anguilla','America/Antigua','America/Araguaina','America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires','America/Argentina/Catamarca','America/Argentina/Cordoba','America/Argentina/Jujuy','America/Argentina/La_Rioja','America/Argentina/Mendoza','America/Argentina/Rio_Gallegos','America/Argentina/Salta','America/Argentina/San_Juan','America/Argentina/San_Luis','America/Argentina/Tucuman','America/Argentina/Ushuaia','America/Aruba','America/Asuncion','America/Atikokan','America/Bahia','America/Bahia_Banderas','America/Barbados','America/Belem','America/Belize','America/Blanc-Sablon','America/Boa_Vista','America/Bogota','America/Boise','America/Cambridge_Bay','America/Campo_Grande','America/Cancun','America/Caracas','America/Cayenne','America/Cayman','America/Chicago','America/Chihuahua','America/Costa_Rica','America/Creston','America/Cuiaba','America/Curacao','America/Danmarkshavn','America/Dawson','America/Dawson_Creek','America/Denver','America/Detroit','America/Dominica','America/Edmonton','America/Eirunepe','America/El_Salvador','America/Fort_Nelson','America/Fortaleza','America/Glace_Bay','America/Goose_Bay','America/Grand_Turk','America/Grenada','America/Guadeloupe','America/Guatemala','America/Guayaquil','America/Guyana','America/Halifax','America/Havana','America/Hermosillo','America/Indiana/Indianapolis','America/Indiana/Knox','America/Indiana/Marengo','America/Indiana/Petersburg','America/Indiana/Tell_City','America/Indiana/Vevay','America/Indiana/Vincennes','America/Indiana/Winamac','America/Inuvik','America/Iqaluit','America/Jamaica','America/Juneau','America/Kentucky/Louisville','America/Kentucky/Monticello','America/Kralendijk','America/La_Paz','America/Lima','America/Los_Angeles','America/Lower_Princes','America/Maceio','America/Managua','America/Manaus','America/Marigot','America/Martinique','America/Matamoros','America/Mazatlan','America/Menominee','America/Merida','America/Metlakatla','America/Mexico_City','America/Miquelon','America/Moncton','America/Monterrey','America/Montevideo','America/Montserrat','America/Nassau','America/New_York','America/Nome','America/Noronha','America/North_Dakota/Beulah','America/North_Dakota/Center','America/North_Dakota/New_Salem','America/Nuuk','America/Ojinaga','America/Panama','America/Pangnirtung','America/Paramaribo','America/Phoenix','America/Port-au-Prince','America/Port_of_Spain','America/Porto_Velho','America/Puerto_Rico','America/Punta_Arenas','America/Rankin_Inlet','America/Recife','America/Regina','America/Resolute','America/Rio_Branco','America/Santarem','America/Santiago','America/Santo_Domingo','America/Sao_Paulo','America/Scoresbysund','America/Sitka','America/St_Barthelemy','America/St_Johns','America/St_Kitts','America/St_Lucia','America/St_Thomas','America/St_Vincent','America/Swift_Current','America/Tegucigalpa','America/Thule','America/Tijuana','America/Toronto','America/Tortola','America/Vancouver','America/Whitehorse','America/Winnipeg','America/Yakutat','America/Yellowknife','Antarctica/Casey','Antarctica/Davis','Antarctica/DumontDUrville','Antarctica/Macquarie','Antarctica/Mawson','Antarctica/McMurdo','Antarctica/Palmer','Antarctica/Rothera','Antarctica/Syowa','Antarctica/Troll','Antarctica/Vostok','Arctic/Longyearbyen','Asia/Aden','Asia/Almaty','Asia/Amman','Asia/Anadyr','Asia/Aqtau','Asia/Aqtobe','Asia/Ashgabat','Asia/Atyrau','Asia/Baghdad','Asia/Bahrain','Asia/Baku','Asia/Bangkok','Asia/Barnaul','Asia/Beirut','Asia/Bishkek','Asia/Brunei','Asia/Chita','Asia/Choibalsan','Asia/Colombo','Asia/Damascus','Asia/Dhaka','Asia/Dili','Asia/Dubai','Asia/Dushanbe','Asia/Famagusta','Asia/Gaza','Asia/Hebron','Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh','Asia/Hong_Kong','Asia/Hovd','Asia/Irkutsk','Asia/Jakarta','Asia/Jayapura','Asia/Jerusalem','Asia/Kabul','Asia/Kamchatka','Asia/Karachi','Asia/Kathmandu','Asia/Khandyga','Asia/Kolkata','Asia/Krasnoyarsk','Asia/Kuala_Lumpur','Asia/Kuching','Asia/Kuwait','Asia/Macau','Asia/Magadan','Asia/Makassar','Asia/Manila','Asia/Muscat','Asia/Nicosia','Asia/Novokuznetsk','Asia/Novosibirsk','Asia/Omsk','Asia/Oral','Asia/Phnom_Penh','Asia/Pontianak','Asia/Pyongyang','Asia/Qatar','Asia/Qostanay','Asia/Qyzylorda','Asia/Riyadh','Asia/Sakhalin','Asia/Samarkand','Asia/Seoul','Asia/Shanghai','Asia/Singapore','Asia/Srednekolymsk','Asia/Taipei','Asia/Tashkent','Asia/Tbilisi','Asia/Tehran','Asia/Thimphu','Asia/Tokyo','Asia/Tomsk','Asia/Ulaanbaatar','Asia/Urumqi','Asia/Ust-Nera','Asia/Vientiane','Asia/Vladivostok','Asia/Yakutsk','Asia/Yangon','Asia/Yekaterinburg','Asia/Yerevan','Atlantic/Azores','Atlantic/Bermuda','Atlantic/Canary','Atlantic/Cape_Verde','Atlantic/Faroe','Atlantic/Madeira','Atlantic/Reykjavik','Atlantic/South_Georgia','Atlantic/St_Helena','Atlantic/Stanley','Australia/Adelaide','Australia/Brisbane','Australia/Broken_Hill','Australia/Darwin','Australia/Eucla','Australia/Hobart','Australia/Lindeman','Australia/Lord_Howe','Australia/Melbourne','Australia/Perth','Australia/Sydney','Europe/Amsterdam','Europe/Andorra','Europe/Astrakhan','Europe/Athens','Europe/Belgrade','Europe/Berlin','Europe/Bratislava','Europe/Brussels','Europe/Bucharest','Europe/Budapest','Europe/Busingen','Europe/Chisinau','Europe/Copenhagen','Europe/Dublin','Europe/Gibraltar','Europe/Guernsey','Europe/Helsinki','Europe/Isle_of_Man','Europe/Istanbul','Europe/Jersey','Europe/Kaliningrad','Europe/Kirov','Europe/Kyiv','Europe/Lisbon','Europe/Ljubljana','Europe/London','Europe/Luxembourg','Europe/Madrid','Europe/Malta','Europe/Mariehamn','Europe/Minsk','Europe/Monaco','Europe/Moscow','Europe/Oslo','Europe/Paris','Europe/Podgorica','Europe/Prague','Europe/Riga','Europe/Rome','Europe/Samara','Europe/San_Marino','Europe/Sarajevo','Europe/Saratov','Europe/Simferopol','Europe/Skopje','Europe/Sofia','Europe/Stockholm','Europe/Tallinn','Europe/Tirane','Europe/Ulyanovsk','Europe/Vaduz','Europe/Vatican','Europe/Vienna','Europe/Vilnius','Europe/Volgograd','Europe/Warsaw','Europe/Zagreb','Europe/Zurich','Indian/Antananarivo','Indian/Chagos','Indian/Christmas','Indian/Cocos','Indian/Comoro','Indian/Kerguelen','Indian/Mahe','Indian/Maldives','Indian/Mauritius','Indian/Mayotte','Indian/Reunion','Pacific/Apia','Pacific/Auckland','Pacific/Bougainville','Pacific/Chatham','Pacific/Chuuk','Pacific/Easter','Pacific/Efate','Pacific/Fakaofo','Pacific/Fiji','Pacific/Funafuti','Pacific/Galapagos','Pacific/Gambier','Pacific/Guadalcanal','Pacific/Guam','Pacific/Honolulu','Pacific/Kanton','Pacific/Kiritimati','Pacific/Kosrae','Pacific/Kwajalein','Pacific/Majuro','Pacific/Marquesas','Pacific/Midway','Pacific/Nauru','Pacific/Niue','Pacific/Norfolk','Pacific/Noumea','Pacific/Pago_Pago','Pacific/Palau','Pacific/Pitcairn','Pacific/Pohnpei','Pacific/Port_Moresby','Pacific/Rarotonga','Pacific/Saipan','Pacific/Tahiti','Pacific/Tarawa','Pacific/Tongatapu','Pacific/Wake','Pacific/Wallis']);
```

What is the problem?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I put `var_dump(TIMEZONE_LIST[0]);` after the definition and it worked fine. Please post a [mre].

Comment: It's not complaining about using an array in your constant, it's complaining about the constant not being defined at all. Make sure you're defining it (or including the file where it's defined) before you try to use it.

Comment: I restarted PHP and the error disappeared.
I am confused!

Answer (score 1):

You're correct:

1. You should be able to [define()] an array:

> https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php
>
> `define(string $constant_name, mixed $value, bool $case_insensitive = false): bool`
>
> 7.0.0 array values are allowed.

2. Your syntax looks correct - I'm unable to reproduce the error.

SUGGESTIONS:

- Check the return value from "define()".
- Test with "var_dump()"
- If it still doesn't work, show is the line that's generating the warning
- Report back what you find.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I restarted PHP and the error disappeared.
I am confused!

Comment: The code appears to have been "correct" to begin with - the confusing part is why you EVER saw the warning.  In the unlikely event it occurs again, please consider the above suggestions.  ALSO: Thank you for copying/pasting the EXACT error message, and the declaration.  It helps :)  FYI, it would have been helpful to see the line CAUSING the warning, too.  I'm voting to "Close/can't reproduce".